# Mapreduce Job Configuration File Location

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, configuration-files, hadoop-yarn

Where do i find job configuration files for a java mapreduce job which is run already, like the overridden default settings and other job specific settings. I am using hadoop 2.6.0. I assume there will be a job configuration file to every job that is run with its user settings. Sorry if this question is repeated was not able to find the exact answer. There is nothing related to this in my yarn-site.xml or mapred-site.xml.

Comment: is there any web service or REST api where we can see these metrics or is it stored in a specific location for all the jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mapred-site.xml`, there is configuration parameter: `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir`.

The description of this parameter is:

> The staging dir used while submitting jobs.

By default, this is set to:

```
/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging
```

This path gets translated into:

```
{Value of config parameter `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir`} + Path.SEPARATOR + user + Path.SEPARATOR + STAGING_CONSTANT
```

For e.g. in my mapred-site.xml, this value is set to:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir</name>
    <value>/user</value>
 </property>
```

So this path gets converted into:

```
/user/{user}/{STAGING_CONSTANT}
```

which is:

```
/user/mballur/.staging/ => Where user -> mballur and STAGING_CONSTANT -> .staging
```

In this folder, you will see your job related settings, **when your job is running**.

For e.g. if my application ID is: application_1450100618247_0018, then the staging folder will be:

```
/user/mballur/.staging/job_1450100618247_0018/
```

In this folder, you can see following files:

```
job.jar
job.split
job.xml
job_1450100618247_0018_1.jhist
job_1450100618247_0018_1_conf.xml
```

Here job.xml contains configuration information about your job. 
**But, when the job is completed (succeeded or failed), the job's staging directory gets deleted.**

**Job History Rest API**:

If you have enabled the History Server, then you can view the history of all the jobs executed so far. For e.g. check the link here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html#Job_Conf_API

Using the following REST query, you can get the job's configuration:

```
GET http://<history server http address:port>/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/{job_id}/conf
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to see the configurations for the job that is already run not the one that is running.Also the history API doesnt give any information about the configuration of the job. It just gives the job counters (and some others). Suppose if i override memory settings for a job and i run it , can i be able to see them after the job is completed.

Comment: I have not enabled the job history server on my setup. But, I am sure, as per the link I have posted, it is possible to query the history of all the executed jobs. I will enable the history server and then update the answer with more details.

Comment: Sorry got what i needed. Thanks a lot :)